# Person Accounts and MC

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

We are connecting Marketing cloud and SF orgs. In Salesforce org we have leads and person accounts. When we connected both environments, We see that we have contacts and accounts as different objects instead of one in MC sync option for Data Sources.

Now my questions is for data extensions which object should i refer to? account or contact?

Answer (score 0):

Our data extensions refer to contacts but this is primarily because our data extensions utilize a contact type field which we use for blasts.

It is worth noting that salesforce documentation does reference that person accounts work with marketing cloud and references a link here to more information:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm&type=5